# Regular expression search

Tags: regex

I've got a list of lines about 1500 in total. I'm trying to write a regular expression to find the ones that do not contain exactly 8 of the string ?d . Now the problem is there could be other characters in the middle of the ?d's. I don't care about the other characters being there, but I do need exactly 8 (total) of the ?d's.

For example, this line is OK: ?d?u?d?u?d?u?d?d?d?d?d (8 ?d)

This line is not: ?d?d?d?d?u?d?d?d?d?u?d (9 ?d)

This line is not: ?d?l?u?d?d?d?d?d?d?d?d (9 ?d)

The problem is the other characters (which are ?u and ?l) can occur anywhere in the line. Is there a regular expression, or series of regular expressions, that can do this? I'm using Notepad++ regular expressions.

It doesn't have to be all in one shot. For instance, I've already done regular expression searches for [\?d]{9,11} which helped, but only eliminated 27 bad lines.

Answer (score 3):

This does what you need:

```
^(?=(?:\?d.*?){8})(?!(?:\?d.*?){9}).+$
```

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/uH5sT1/1)

It starts from the beginning, ensures the line contains 8 `?d` groups, but rejects it if it contains 9 of them (or more). Full explanation:

- `^` start of the string
- `(?=(?:\?d.*?){8})` positive lookahead: must be followed by this pattern: `(?:\?d.*?){8}`

  - `\?d.*?` matches the literal string `?d`, followed by zero or more characters, matching as few as necessary
  - `{8}` 8 occurrences in a row of the preceding pattern
- `(?!(?:\?d.*?){9})` negative lookahead: must not be followed by this pattern: `(?:\?d.*?){9}`

  - `\?d.*?` matches the literal string `?d`, followed by zero or more characters, matching as few as necessary
  - `{9}` 9 occurrences in a row of the preceding pattern
- `.+` match any characters
- `$` end of the string

Comment: This is going to take a while to understand, but thanks.

Comment: Glad to help. Please see my additional explanation above. There's an even more complete explanation on the right side of the page when you go to [**the demo linked in my answer**](https://regex101.com/r/uH5sT1/1).

Comment: if this is a perfect answer, why not mark it as `the answer'? so the author will get some reputation from it?

Answer (score 0):

Edited
use this pattern

```
^(?!(?:(?:[^?]|\?(?!d))*?\?d){8}(?:[^?]|\?(?!d))*$)(.*)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/159)

Comment: That matches the ones which have exactly 8 `?d`s. OP asked for one which matches the lines which don't have 8.

Answer (score 0):

```
^(?!(?:[^d]*\?d){8}$).*$
```

You can try this simple regex.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/uH5sT1/2